# Return binary results with newline increments

Tags: c++, binary, hex

I am trying to convert hex to binary, taking in a text file which has:

3c011001
34300000
8e080000
20090003
11200004

but it is outputing the binary at the same line:

0011 1100 0000 0001 0001 0000 0000 0001 0011 0100 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 1110 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000

Id like to return it like this:

0011 1100 0000 0001 0001 0000 0000 0001

0011 0100 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

etc.. for each line of hex.

```
string hex (string sHex)
{
   string sReturn = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < sHex.length (); ++i)
   {
    switch (sHex [i])
    {
        case '0': sReturn.append ("0000 "); break;
        case '1': sReturn.append ("0001 "); break;
        case '2': sReturn.append ("0010 "); break;
        case '3': sReturn.append ("0011 "); break;
        case '4': sReturn.append ("0100 "); break;
        case '5': sReturn.append ("0101 "); break;
        case '6': sReturn.append ("0110 "); break;
        case '7': sReturn.append ("0111 "); break;
        case '8': sReturn.append ("1000 "); break;
        case '9': sReturn.append ("1001 "); break;
        case 'a': sReturn.append ("1010 "); break;
        case 'b': sReturn.append ("1011 "); break;
        case 'c': sReturn.append ("1100 "); break;
        case 'd': sReturn.append ("1101 "); break;
        case 'e': sReturn.append ("1110 "); break;
        case 'f': sReturn.append ("1111 "); break;
    }
  }
  return sReturn;
  }

int main() {
  ifstream file;
  file.open("MachineCode.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
  {
    cout << "ERROR";
  } else {
    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << file.rdbuf();
    string contents = strStream.str();
    cout << hex(contents) << endl;

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `case ' ': sReturn.append ("\n "); break;`

Comment: You will need to modify `hex()` to add a newline when `bytecnt == 8` or `nibblecnt == 16`. The other option is to provide output within `hex()`, but that violates separating implementation and interface. (if you always have 8-byte whitespace separated input, then I like @drescherjm approach as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new case which detects when there is a new line from the input to add a new line to the output.

```
case '\n': sReturn.append ("\n"); break;
```